# Запрос HttpDelete на удаление нескольких записей отрабатывает только 1-ую запись

Tags: javascript, ajax

Проект asp net core. Есть APIController обрабатывающий удаление записи:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class APIFriendsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly Db_usersContext _context;

        public APIFriendsController(Db_usersContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // DELETE: api/APIFriends/DeleteFriend/5
        [HttpDelete("DeleteFriend/{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Friend>> DeleteFriend(long id)
        {
            var friend = await _context.Friend.FindAsync(id);
            if (friend == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Friend.Remove(friend);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return friend;
        }       
    }
```

На странице JS функцию, которая перебирает все строки body table, выбирает помеченные на удаление, и отправляет запрос на сервер для удаления выбранных записей:

```
function deleteSelected(idObject) {

        var table = document.getElementById(idObject);
        var rows = table.rows;
        var total = 0;

        for (var i = 1, iLen = rows.length - 1; i < iLen; i++) {
            var checked_ = table.rows[i].cells[21].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked;
            if (checked_ == true) {

                var idFriend = table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
                idFriend = idFriend.trim();
                var url_ = "http://localhost:48329/api/APIFriends/DeleteFriend/" + idFriend;

                $.ajax({
                    url: url_,
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert('Пользователи удалены');
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function (result, status, er) {
                        alert("error: " + result + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что она завершается после удаления 1-ой выделенной записи, а последующие функция уже не обрабатывает.
В чем причина? Как можно исправить?

Comment: Во-первых вместо `for (var i = 1` напишите `for (let i = 1`. Это должно решить проблему. А во-вторых. Вместо того, чтобы гонять это в цикле - правильно будет собрать данные и кучкой в одном запросе отослать то, что нужно удалить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, на счет кучки вы совершенно правы, но я не знаю как это сделать. Как сформировать такой запрос? Можете пример привести или ссылочку, пожалуйста?

Comment: Нужно метод сделать DeleteFriends, который будет принимать, например, строку идентификаторов, разделённых запятой. А в ajax запросе, соответственно передавать её, типа `123,124,125`.  Либо тоже самое, только передавать массив и принимать массив